# App needs to be restarted even when runtime permission for accessing files is granted using WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, android-permissions

App needs to be restarted even when runtime permission for accessing files is granted  using WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

I try to get the required permission at the start of the app in a class called `SplashScreen` it self

I use 
`Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

at the beginning of the app itself

here is the code that I tried

```
    private void requestPermission() {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                ShowAlert();


            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }



 public void ShowAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.setTitle("PERMISSION REQUIRED ...");

        alertDialog.setMessage("PERMISSION REQUIRED TO READ FILES");


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("GRANT PERMISSION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

                dialog.cancel();




            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Then in a `service` I try to use the file using

```
try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(song_Path);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Paused = false;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {


        }
```

If real time permission is granted as above there should be no need to restart the app, but when I try to access files for the first time after granting permissions in the `try catch` I get an `IOException` stating permission not granted and file is not accessible, once i restart the app the file can be accessed

what needs to be done , so that there is no need to restart the app to access the file for the first time itself

Comment: do you have cyanogenMod?

Comment: no I am trying on emulator

Comment: try it on a real device, usually it should work. could be a emulator dependant behaviour.

Comment: where is your onRequestPermissionsResult method implemented?

Comment: I am currently looking into It , how can we handle  never show again in android run time permision

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. That would include the complete Java stack trace associated with the exception, along with the actual code generating that exception.